# How to disable selection option after selecting 5 store in Android?

Tags: android-layout, listview, android-studio

How to disable selection option after selecting 5 stores in Android? Here is the image of layout XML file:

[image: here is the image of layout xml file]

StoreSelect.java  code

https://gist.github.com/mdsami/7740d1ea418a27a050c30c57dbf5cfb0

selectstore.xml

https://gist.github.com/mdsami/e89afc9b6379b657337dd785e947a8b2

Comment: add code to see what have you done?

Comment: Please include your code *in your question*, not in external links. Your question will be invalid if the external links are broken.

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l)
  {
    CheckedTextView item=(CheckedTextView) view;
    boolean b=item.isChecked();
    // make your own count for max 5, if count > 5, you can show some message, or uncheck it by code.
  }
});
```